# GTK why call to gtk_widget_queue_draw does not work from inside the fucntion?

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

```
g_idle_add((GSourceFunc)gtk_widget_queue_draw, drawing_area);
```

When I do this it works (I know it is UB as `gtk_widget_queue_draw` does not return value), but I have 100% processor time because of UB.

When I call it indirectly, it does not draw:

```
gboolean GUL_draw_idle(gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(user_data);
    return FALSE;
}

g_idle_add((GSourceFunc)GUL_draw_idle, drawing_area);
```

Why? As I understand `gtk_widget_queue_draw` should draw everything in the drawing queue.